# How do we get the Model value of each input text box?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

## AngularJS Scope

```js
$scope.myArrayOfPrimitives = [ 11, 22, 33, 44 ];
```

```html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, num) in myArrayOfPrimitives">
        <input ng-model="num">
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" ng-click="getAllNumTextModelValue=()" value="submit">
```

Each `ng-repeat`, that will create an child scope and that child scope will be prototypically inherit from the parent scope(`childscope = scope.$new()`) - So, the parent scope can be accessible with in the "`li`" tag.. I'm using "num" as a model name for the input text box for each child scope. So, there will be an model created and that will store "num" model value on their child scope. So, there won't be any mismatch even though angular is an Two way binding.

I want to get all the "num" model value when I click on submit button.

Can you please advise me what is the best way of doing that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you can use $index which give you the index of your input. Look and try this following code.

- {{num[$index]}} : this will return you the value of the input. 
  Exemple: input 1 = 15 so num[0] = 15

```js
$scope.myArrayOfPrimitives = [ 11, 22, 33, 44 ];
```

```html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, num) in myArrayOfPrimitives">
        <input ng-model="num[$index]">{{num[$index]}} // 
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" ng-click="getAllNumTextModelValue=()" value="submit">
```

Comment: I think, you are not getting my points.... As you see the example, Each ng-repeat usually create an child scope of its parent... like childscope = scope.$new() -- And this is the scope usually store the value of the current model - So, the value changed in this model doesn't exist on the $scope object that will reside on the child scope -- when i click the button that will trigger the getAllNumTextModelValue method and that need to return the child scope its $scope object..

Comment: And, I know, this can be done using the object reference, but, I wanted to know how to achieve this through primitive Types like I gave in the examples.. Please advise me if i'm wrong